# Change status automatically in oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two table

```
user (user_id, username, status )
```

status -->  (1 - active, 0 - passive)

```
user_work (user_work_id, user_id, status)
```

status -->  (1 - active, 0 - passive)

How set automatically in **user** table status = 0 if in **user_work** table don't have active status for some user. If have for some user in **user_work** active status in **user** table set status = 1

Is it possible with triger or maybe use some other solution like call some procedure?

Comment: I guess you can't insert or update a row in user_work table if the user does not exist in the user table. Am I right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by `statement trigger`, something like this should serve the purpose. Of course, you should start from a cleaning point, it means first you need to update all the values in the `user` table with the latest status of the `user_work` table.

I believe as well that @Littlefoot statement is correct, keeping the same field in two tables is never a good idea.

What I give you here is a solution to maintain the status in your user table using changes or new entries in the user_work table. I think it is what you asked for.

Let's imagine this scenario *( I used different names for the tables )*

```
SQL> create table user_names ( user_id number, username varchar2(1) , status varchar2(1) ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into user_names values ( 1 , 'A' , 1 );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into user_names values ( 2 , 'B' , 1 );

1 row created.

SQL> create table user_work ( user_work_id number, user_id number, status varchar2(1) ) ;

Table created.
```

In this scenario, I have no rows yet in the `user_work` table, so let's create the statement trigger to update or insert

```
SQL> create or replace trigger upd_status_user 
after insert or update on user_work
begin 
    merge into user_names t 
    using ( select * from user_work ) s 
    on ( t.user_id = s.user_id ) 
    when matched then 
    update set t.status = s.status 
    where 
    s.user_work_id = ( select max(user_work_id) from user_work s where t.user_id = s.user_id ) ;
end;
/

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Now we test it

```
SQL> insert into user_work values ( 100 , 1 , 1 );

1 row created.

SQL> commit ;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from user_names ;

   USER_ID U S
---------- - -
         1 A 1
         2 B 1

SQL> insert into user_work values ( 101 , 1 , 0 );

1 row created.

SQL> commit ;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from user_names ;

   USER_ID U S
---------- - -
         1 A 0
         2 B 1

SQL> insert into user_work values ( 102 , 1 , 1 ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> commit ;

Commit complete.

SQL>  select * from user_names ;

   USER_ID U S
---------- - -
         1 A 1
         2 B 1
```

You can see the changes in user_names table ( your user table ) when I am inserting new records in the user_work table , maintaining the latest status.

If I update, it happens the same

```
SQL> update user_work set status = 0 where user_work_id=102 ;

1 row updated.

SQL> commit ;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from user_names ;

   USER_ID U S
---------- - -
         1 A 0
         2 B 1
```

Comment: @Pointer, do you have any feedback ?

Comment: vote for your answer I will try implement in my example.

Comment: thank you @Pointer. If it solves your issue, please accept the answer

Answer (score 5):

From my point of view, that would be a bad idea as you'd keep `status` information in two tables (so bye-bye *normalization*). If you have to know someone's status, query it.

Sample tables:

```
SQL> select * from t_user;

   USER_ID USERNAM
---------- -------
         1 Little
         2 Foot
         3 Pointer     --> doesn't have STATUS in USER_WORK

SQL> select * from user_work;

USER_WORK_ID    USER_ID     STATUS
------------ ---------- ----------
         100          1          0
         101          1          1   --> last status for USER_ID = 1 is 1
         102          2          1   --> last (and only) status for USER_ID = 2 is 1

SQL>
```

Query (presuming that last status (sorted by `USER_WORK_ID` in descending order is someone's current status; if there's no row in `USER_WORK` table, then status = `0`).

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select w.user_id, w.status,
  3            row_number() over (partition by w.user_id order by w.user_work_id desc) rn
  4     from user_work w
  5    )
  6  select u.user_id, u.username, nvl(t.status, 0) status
  7  from t_user u left join temp t on t.user_id = u.user_id
  8                                and t.rn = 1;

   USER_ID USERNAM     STATUS
---------- ------- ----------
         1 Little           1
         2 Foot             1
         3 Pointer          0

SQL>
```

Or, a simple way, create a **view**:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_user_status as
  2  with temp as
  3    (select w.user_id, w.status,
  4            row_number() over (partition by w.user_id order by w.user_work_id desc) rn
  5     from user_work w
  6    )
  7  select u.user_id, u.username, nvl(t.status, 0) status
  8  from t_user u left join temp t on t.user_id = u.user_id
  9                                and t.rn = 1;

View created.

SQL> select * From v_user_status;

   USER_ID USERNAM     STATUS
---------- ------- ----------
         1 Little           1
         2 Foot             1
         3 Pointer          0

SQL>
```

Comment: I agree that this should not be stored redundantly. As I read it it even sounds as if this is about having *any* `user_work.status = 1` or not, i.e. not the *last* one. That would make the query even simpler: `select user,_id, max(status) from user_work group by user_id`.

Comment: Right, @Thorsten. I thought that statuses change over time and that last status is what we want to know. Though, if it were something like "I was pregnant. Now I'm not." and you want to know "was I ever pregnant?", then MAX(STATUS) would do. Don't forget to outer join that table with T_USER table because I (as a *male*) wasn't pregnant and probably won't ever be :), so my status would be 0.

Answer (score 0):

one option , if time is not tricky you can create a job to check it hourly and set status like this :

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(JOB_NAME        => 'job_name',
                            JOB_TYPE        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
                            JOB_ACTION      => 'BEGIN
UPDATE USER
   SET STATUS = 0
 WHERE USER_ID NOT IN (SELECT USER_ID FROM USER_WORK W WHERE STATUS = 1);
COMMIT;
 END;',
                            START_DATE      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
                            REPEAT_INTERVAL => 'freq=hourly; byminute=0; bysecond=0;',
                            ENABLED         => TRUE);
END;
```

Note: You can use triggers too, but in my oppinion status should be stored on one place and should directly updated on specific operations when its needed

Answer (score 0):

So, you're kinda provided with almost all possible option except one I believe.
If following Littlefoot's answer is not an option for you, you may try to use virtual columns.

1. Create user_work table:

   ```
   create table user_work(user_work_id number, user_id number, status number);
   ```
2. Create stored function to calculate status for a user:

   ```
    create or replace function get_status(p_user_id number) return number deterministic
    is
      active_cnt number := 0;
    begin
      select count(1)
        into active_cnt
        from user_work uw
       where uw.user_id = p_user_id;

      if active_cnt > 0 then
        return 1;
      else
        return 0;
      end if;
    end;
   ```
3. Create table user_tab as following:

   ```
    create table user_tab(user_id number, status generated always as (get_status(user_id)) virtual);
   ```

Now, let's test:

```
insert into user_tab(user_id) values(1);
insert into user_tab(user_id) values(2);
insert into user_work(user_work_id, user_id, status) values(1, 1, 1);

select * from user_tab;
```

| user_id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |